# Declare length of int column in db schema

Tags: magento2, db-schema

How to declare int length in Magento 2.4 db_schema file?

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain what is reason to set length of `int` column?

The `int` uses `4 bytes` (`32 bits`) and can be `unsigned` with range from `0` to `4294967295` and `signed` with range from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

MySQL will store the value regardless from length value, the length affect to formatter (padding length) in console and when set `ZEROFILL` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link. This explains your need.

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`padding="10"`** to define the size of int in `db_schema.xml`

```
<column xsi:type="int" name="id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Entity ID"/>
```